# UE4 Importing ArchViz Interior project becomes too bright

Tags: unreal-engine4

When I migrate ArchVizInterior project in my project, then it imports correctly, but it becomes too bright. The lights have the same intensity. What is going wrong? I have enabled Ray-tracing

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found it

You must enable "GPU Lightmass" plugin and also check Engine->Rendering settings to have the same with the original ArchVizInterior project. See also here:

https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/RenderingAndGraphics/GPULightmass/

Comment: Of course you should restart the editor, and have the patience to wait for all the shaders to recompile :)